# Is there any way to make a div fadeIn without having it's opacity at 100% when loading the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

So I'm only trying to make a div fade In like a success pop up. I'm working with MVC and I'm only trying to call my div and call fadeIn(3000) on it. What happens is the div appears at full opacity, then disappears and ends up fading in after that.

I'm trying to do something like this, but without clicking a button. I want my fade in to appear after my ajax call, so after loading the page :
https://fr.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/jquery-example-fadein-fadeout-and-fadetoggle/5312653019447296

My function :

```
if ($("#alertMsg").is(':visible')) {
$(#"alertMsg").delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

And this is my Razor code :

```
@if (ViewBag.UserMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success font-weight-bold d-inline-block" style="display: none" id="alertMsg" role="alert">
        @ViewBag.UserMessage
    </div>
}
```

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: What if you set the initial opacity to `0` in the `style` attribute?

Comment: sounds like you are starting the page with the div already visible.

Comment: display: none !important; (dont forget the semicolon)

Comment: Correct `$(#"alertMsg")` to `$("#alertMsg")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to invert your `if`

```js
if (!$("#alertMsg").is(':visible')) {
 $("#alertMsg").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
BEFORE
</p>
<div style="display: none;" id="alertMsg" role="alert">
        BLAH!!
</div>
<p>
AFTER
</p>
```

This isn't really anything to do with MVC, etc, it's pure javascript